Beef Uncaught TypeError: domain is undefined
I am having problem regarding my beef which i am setting for my testing purpose below is my config file
beef:
version: '0.5.4.0'
# More verbose messages (server-side)
debug: false
# More verbose messages (client-side)
client_debug: false
# Used for generating secure tokens
crypto_default_value_length: 80



# Credentials to authenticate in BeEF.
# Used by both the RESTful API and the Admin interface
credentials:
    user:   "beef"
    passwd: "unknown3424"

# Interface / IP restrictions
restrictions:
    # subnet of IP addresses that can hook to the framework
    permitted_hooking_subnet: ["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
    # subnet of IP addresses that can connect to the admin UI
    #permitted_ui_subnet: ["127.0.0.1/32", "::1/128"]
    permitted_ui_subnet: ["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
    # subnet of IP addresses that cannot be hooked by the framework
    excluded_hooking_subnet: []
    # slow API calls to 1 every  api_attempt_delay  seconds
    api_attempt_delay: "0.05"

# HTTP server 
http:
    debug: false #Thin::Logging.debug, very verbose. Prints also full exception stack trace.
    host: "0.0.0.0"
    port: "3000"

    # Decrease this setting to 1,000 (ms) if you want more responsiveness
    #  when sending modules and retrieving results.
    # NOTE: A poll timeout of less than 5,000 (ms) might impact performance
    #  when hooking lots of browsers (50+).
    # Enabling WebSockets is generally better (beef.websocket.enable)
    xhr_poll_timeout: 1000

    # Public Domain Name / Reverse Proxy / Port Forwarding
    #
    # In order for the client-side BeEF JavaScript hook to be able to connect to BeEF,
    # the hook JavaScript needs to be generated with the correct connect-back details.
    #
    # If you're using a public domain name, reverse proxy, or port forwarding you must
    # configure the public-facing connection details here.

    #public:
    #    host: "beef.local" # public hostname/IP address
    #    port: "443" # public port (443 if the public server is using HTTPS)
    #    https: false # true/false

    # If using any reverse proxy you should also set allow_reverse_proxy to true below.
    # Note that this causes the BeEF server to trust the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header.
    # If the BeEF server is directly accessible, clients can spoof their connecting
    # IP address using this header to bypass the IP address permissions/exclusions.

    allow_reverse_proxy: true

    # Hook
    hook_file: "/hook.js"
    hook_session_name: "BEEFHOOK"

    # Allow one or multiple origins to access the RESTful API using CORS
    # For multiple origins use: "http://browserhacker.com, http://domain2.com"
    restful_api:
        allow_cors: false
        cors_allowed_domains: "http://browserhacker.com"

    # Prefer WebSockets over XHR-polling when possible.
    websocket:
        enable: false
        port: 61985 # WS: good success rate through proxies
        # Use encrypted 'WebSocketSecure'
        # NOTE: works only on HTTPS domains and with HTTPS support enabled in BeEF
        secure: true
        secure_port: 61986 # WSSecure
        ws_poll_timeout: 5000 # poll BeEF every x second, this affects how often the browser can have a command execute on it
        ws_connect_timeout: 500 # useful to help fingerprinting finish before establishing the WS channel

    # Imitate a specified web server (default root page, 404 default error page, 'Server' HTTP response header)
    web_server_imitation:
        enable: true
        type: "nginx" # Supported: apache, iis, nginx
        hook_404: false # inject BeEF hook in HTTP 404 responses
        hook_root: false # inject BeEF hook in the server home page
    # Experimental HTTPS support for the hook / admin / all other Thin managed web services
    https:
        enable: false
        # In production environments, be sure to use a valid certificate signed for the value
        # used in beef.http.public (the domain name of the server where you run BeEF)
        key: "beef_key.pem"
        cert: "beef_cert.pem"

database:
    file: "beef.db"

# Autorun Rule Engine
autorun:
    # this is used when rule chain_mode type is nested-forward, needed as command results are checked via setInterval
    # to ensure that we can wait for async command results. The timeout is needed to prevent infinite loops or eventually
    # continue execution regardless of results.
    # If you're chaining multiple async modules, and you expect them to complete in more than 5 seconds, increase the timeout.
    result_poll_interval: 300
    result_poll_timeout: 5000

    # If the modules doesn't return status/results and timeout exceeded, continue anyway with the chain.
    # This is useful to call modules (nested-forward chain mode) that are not returning their status/results.
    continue_after_timeout: true

# Enables DNS lookups on zombie IP addresses
dns_hostname_lookup: false

# IP Geolocation
geoip:
    enable: true
    # GeoLite2 City database created by MaxMind, available from https://www.maxmind.com
    database: '/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'

# You may override default extension configuration parameters here
# Note: additional experimental extensions are available in the 'extensions' directory
#       and can be enabled via their respective 'config.yaml' file
extension:
    admin_ui:
        enable: true
        base_path: "/ui"
    demos:
        enable: true
    events:
        enable: true
    evasion:
        enable: false
    requester:
        enable: true
    proxy:
        enable: true
    network:
        enable: true
    metasploit:
        enable: false
    social_engineering:
        enable: true
    xssrays:
        enable: true

and below is my nginx reverse proxy
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name mysite.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

set $upstream 127.0.0.1:3000;
    location / {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection “”;
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
``server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;


set $upstream 127.0.0.1:3000;
    location / {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection “”;
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
when i authenticate it works fine with my domain but when i share the weblink most specifically the butcher site link it gives error which are Uncaught TypeError: domain is undefined. i dont know hwy it is happening. I hope somebody will help me
